# Phalcon PHP Framework : Routes are not generating results, getting The route contains invalid paths

Tags: nginx

I am new to Phalcon and first-time using MVC, I did the all Configuration settings by following Phalcon documentation. But,somewhere I have done something Wrong with my code. I am using NGINX server, I want you to please guide me to the right track!

```
My bootstrap file:- public/index.php 
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {

    /**
     * Read the configuration
     */
    $config = include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/config.php";

    /**
     * Read auto-loader
     */
    include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/loader.php";

    /**
     * Read services
     */
    include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/services.php";

    $di->set('router', function(){
    require __DIR__.'/../app/config/routes.php';
    return $router;
    });


    /**
     * Handle the request
     */
    $application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);
    $application->setDI($di);

    echo $application->handle()->getContent();


} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

try {

    //Register an autoloader
    $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
    $loader->registerDirs(array(
        'app/controllers/',
        'app/models/'
    ))->register();

    //Create a DI
    $di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

    //Setup the database service
    $di->set('db', function(){
        return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
            "host" => "localhost",
            "username" => "root",
            "password" => "k.p.cn1183",
            "dbname" => "phalcon_signup"
        ));
    });

    //Setup the view component
    $di->set('view', function(){
        $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
        $view->setViewsDir('app/views/');
        return $view;
    });

    //Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "tutorial" folder
    $di->set('url', function(){
        $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
        $url->setBaseUri('/');
        return $url;
    });


} catch(\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
     echo "PhalconException: ", $e->getMessage();
}
?>
My routes.php file:- in -> app/config/routes.php

<?php

  use Phalcon\Mvc\Router;

  $router = new Router();

  $router->add("/new",function(){
  echo "Welcome,You are here..!!";
});

$router->handle();
return $router;

?>
 here above,I am just doing a simple program that echo "Welcome,You are here..!!";


And i have followed the instructions from documentation for .htaccess file

The 1st .htaccess file is from:-public/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

The 2nd .htaccess fie is from:-[my project folder->test/.htaccess]
,includes:-

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


I am almost doing this since 2 days,but i am not getting the result..!!
am i doing anything wrong here..??or any modifications are required with code..!!If possible providing with example would be appreciated..!! 
Hope for good resut..!!
I thank you in advance..!!
```